# error copying from csv to cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I am trying to copy from csv to cassandra db like this:

```
cqlsh:customer_details> copy real_estate (street,city,zip,state) from 'C:\Users\
kiriti.k\Desktop\Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ';' AND
HEADER = TRUE;
```

But getting an error:

```
Starting copy of customer_details.real_estate with columns ['street', 'city', 'z
ip', 'state'].

Error starting import process:

    Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
    can only join a started process
    cqlsh:customer_details> Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\lib\multiprocessing\forking.p
    y", line 380, in main
        prepare(preparation_data)
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\lib\multiprocessing\forking.p
    y", line 489, in prepare
        file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
    ImportError: No module named cqlsh
```

I have no idea what this error means. I am very new to cassandra family. Anyone already debbuged this kind of issue. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Does cqlsh work at all or is it just a copy command issue? I suspect this is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3767 except 3767 was on osx with homebrew missing a dependency and you are running windows. To get around it you can

1) try brian's cassandra-loader which has no python dependencies

https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

or

2) install the python dependencies as shown in the ticket

> download
>   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/pylib/setup.py, and
>   and cqlshlib from
>   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/, and
>   then run python install setup.py.

Comment: Hi phact, I downloaded brain's cassandra-loader but how do I run it? Its not associated with any file type and windows doesn't recognise it